# Telephone number format should be international,Is there any Regex for phone number validation in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, formatting, phone-number

Telephone number should be international and user has to enter the complete phone number with country code.

For that I need a regex for formatting the phone number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For real regex testing use [RegexKitLite](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/RegexKitLite/).

As for the regular expression itself, something like this (from [Validate Phone Numbers: A Detailed Guide](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/validate-phone-number#r4-3)) should work:

```
^\+(?:[0-9] ?){6,14}[0-9]$
```

Note that when you specify it in your code you need to escape the backslash character (\), so it would look like this:

```
NSString *regexString = @"^\\+(?:[0-9] ?){6,14}[0-9]$";
```

Comment: Thank you its simple and nice

Comment: Glad you like it. If this answer helped you, please check the checkmark next to it.

Comment: If user want to add this symbol "-"  and alphabets for example 1-800-MY-APPLE then how to validate for given format

Comment: @ Matthew Frederick:If user want to add this symbol "-" and alphabets for example 1-800-MY-APPLE then how to validate for given format. And how many character do we need to include that is greater than 12 characters

Comment: I believe you can replace the space (right after the first [0-9]) with [ \-] which would mean a space or a -. In the NSString you would need to escape the backslash: [ \\-] .

Comment: As noted in the link to the Validate Phone Numbers blog entry, this will validate one or more numbers followed by a space (now a space or a dash), and require that these groups be there 6 to 14 times, ending with a number.