# Validating the phone numbers

Tags: iphone, ios4, regexkit

I want to have only 13 numeric values or the 13numeric values can be prefixed with "+" sysmbol.so the + is not mandatory 
Example : 1234567891234
another example is : +1234567891234

[Telephone number format should be international,Is there any Regex for phone number validation in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301363/telephone-number-format-should-be-international-is-there-any-regex-for-phone-num)

I have tried the above link , but this +1234545 but i want to have only 13 numarals or + can be prefixed with that 13 numerals.

Please let me know , what can i change it here

This is the code i tried

```
NSString * forNumeric = @"^\\+(?:[0-9] ?){6,14}[0-9]$";

    BOOL isMatch = [[textFieldRounded text] isMatchedByRegex:forNumeric];

    if (isMatch == YES){

        NSLog(@"Matched");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Not matched");
    }
```

Comment: IS not is possible using the regular expressions? pls let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^(\+?)(\d{13})$` should do the trick, escape the slashes for objective-C usage. 
13 digits, with an options `+` prefix.

If you want to play with regexp expressions you can use services like [this one](http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/) for visual feedback, very handy.

```
NSString * forNumeric = @"^(\\+?)(\\d{13})$";
```

Comment: In this case, The user has to enter a 13 digit number. What can be done if we want the user to enter anything less than 13 numbers? Like maybe 9-10 digits.

Comment: `NSString * forNumeric = @"^(\\+?)(\\d{a,b})$";`

Just replace a and b with the inclusive range you want, e.g. a=9, b=10.

Answer (score 4):

```
    NSString * regex = @"((07|00447|004407|\\+4407|\\+447)\\d{9})";
```

Having found the leading 0 or the leading +44 once, why search for it again?

Basic simplification leads to

```
    NSString * regex = @"((07|00440?7|\\+440?7)\\d{9})";
```

then to

```
    NSString * regex = @"((07|(00|\\+)440?7)\\d{9})";
```

then to

```
    NSString * regex = @"((0|(00|\\+)440?)7\\d{9})";
```

but 00 isn't the only common dial prefix, 011 is used in the US and Canada.

Adding that, and turning the order round, gives:

```
    NSString * regex = @"(^((0(0|11)|\\+)440?|0)7\\d{9}$)";
```

or preferably

```
    NSString * regex = @"(^(?:(?:0(?:0|11)|\\+)(44)0?|0)(7\\d{9}$))";
```

allowing 00447, 011447, +447, 004407, 0114407, +4407, 07 at the beginning, and with non-capturing groups.

For wider input format matching, allowing various punctuation (hyphens, brackets, spaces) use

```
    NSString * regex = @"(^\\(?(?:(?:0(?:0|11)\\)?[\\s-]?\\(?|\\+)(44)\\)?[\\s-]?\\(?(?:0\\)?[\\s-]?\\(?)?|0)(7\\d{9})$)";
```

Extract the 44 country code in $1 (null if number entered as 07...) and the 10-digit NSN in $2.

However, be aware that numbers beginning 070 and 076 (apart from 07624) are NOT mobile numbers.

The final pattern:

```
    NSString * regex = @"(^\\(?(?:(?:0(?:0|11)\\)?[\\s-]?\\(?|\\+)(44)\\)?[\\s-]?\\(?(?:0\\)?[\\s-]?\\(?)?|0)(7([1-5789]\\d{2}|624)\\)?[\\s-]?\\d{6}))$)";
```

Extract the NSN in $2 then remove all non-digits from it for further processing.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDataDetector *matchdetector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypePhoneNumber
                                                                error:&error];
NSUInteger matchNumber = [matchdetector numberOfMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
```

If you  use `UITextField` then:

```
textField.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber;
```

Comment: `dataDetectorTypes` are not for textfields.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
NSString *forNumeric = @"\\+?[0-9]{6,13}";
NSPredicate *predicate;
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self matches %@", forNumeric];
BOOL isMatch = [predicate evaluateWithObject:@"+1234567890123"];

if (isMatch) NSLog(@"Matched");
else NSLog(@"Not matched");
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try using a NSDataDetector:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDataDetector_Class/Reference/Reference.html

available in iOS4+

Comment: brother just needs a simple regex.

Answer (score 0):

The following is what I do for validating UK mobile numbers:

```
- (BOOL) isValidPhoneNumber
{
    NSString * regex = @"((07|00447|004407|\\+4407|\\+447)\\d{9})";
    NSPredicate *testPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regex]; 
    BOOL validationResult = [testPredicate evaluateWithObject: self];
    return validationResult;
}
```

See if it helps you